# show placeholder in inputField Tag , throwing error Unsupported attribute placeholder in <apex:InputField>

Tags: apex, visualforce, apexinputfield

Showing Error Unsupported attribute placeholder in

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:form>
       <apex:InputField value="{!con.firstName}" styleclass="slds-input" 
                     placeholder="Enter Account Name For Search!"/>
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no placeholder attribute in apex inputField

you need to specify html-placeholder. This way it will work

```
<apex:InputText value="{!searchBoxstring}" label="Search" styleclass="slds-input" 
                                        html-placeholder="Enter Account Name For Search!"/>
```

Comment: Not Working this html-placeholder.. and i have add docType="html-5.0" at <apex:page> tag still not working

Comment: @VipinIndora instead of using apex:inputField try with apex:inputText ?

Comment: @VipinIndora, may i ask which browser you are using?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m